# Special Characters Lost in Process InputStream

Tags: java, character-encoding

This isn't a repeat of a previous question, I have found out the issue is with the Process.

I have a problem with my program whereby special characters are seemingly lost in the InputStream of a Java Process.

The code I am using is as follows:

```
String command = "/usr/local/bin/getTitle <URL>";
Process shellCommand = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(shellCommand.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
String output = null;
while ((output = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(output);
}
```

If I run the 'command' from the command line, I get the following output:

```
PSY_-_GANGNAM_STYLE_(강남스타일)_M_V
```

However, the output of System.out.println(output); is as follows:

```
PSY_-_GANGNAM_STYLE_()_M_V
```

And this completely breaks my program.

I'm completely stumped, and I haven't found anything even remotely related to this in my search. Any help greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:**

If I change command as follows:

```
String command="echo 'PSY_-_GANGNAM_STYLE_(강남스 타일)_M_V'";
```

Then when printing the output the special characters are displayed correctly. Does this help in understanding where the problem lies?

Comment: How exactly are you running this? Where exactly does `System.out` point to? If you're running this in an IDE like Eclipse and the `System.out` points to its console, then you'd need to configure it separately to use UTF-8 as well.

Comment: @BalusC I'm running this in Eclipse, I'm only using System.out for debugging purposes. The character encoding in Eclipse has also separately been set to use UTF-8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems pretty clear that this problem is caused by mismatching character encodings somewhere.  The two places it could be are in the Reader stack that is reading from the external process, or the PrintStream stack for `System.out`.  (The latter seems unlikely).

Here's what I'd do:

- Run the `locale` command from the command line to see what character encoding is used by your command shell.
- Check that the encoding is the same as the Java default character encoding
- Check that they are both the same as the encoding you are using to read from the external process.  (You have hard-wired that to "UTF-8" ...)

If that doesn't reveal the source of the problem, try replacing the `command` string with `"locale"` to see what locale settings get propagated to the external process.

And if that doesn't work, try capturing the output from the external command as bytes, displaying them in hexadecimal, and trying to hand decode them as UTF-8 and as other possible character sets.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the output of locale in the console is: "en_GB.UTF-8". The default encoding for Java is set to "UTF-8". Replacing command with locale prints out the same but to the console. I'm not sure how I can capture the output as bytes because the ByteArrayInputStream needs the output as a parameter which is not accessible at this point in the program.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the command returns a string in the default encoding of the OS, i.e. Mac OS Roman on Mac. You're reading it as UTF-8. If you figure out what the encoding is and pass that to the constructor of your InputStreamReader it should give better results.

If you create the string in Java and then pass that around it works fine, because then the string isn't generated by the OS, but by your Java process.

Comment: The default Java encoding is also UTF-8. Also if the script is run on the command line the encoding is correct. Do you think it's the Runtime which is losing the characters?

Comment: @Cristian: Unless `getTitle` is also a Java process, why do you think the Java default encoding would affect the output of the `getTitle` process?

Comment: @JonSkeet getTitle is a shell script, but this script outputs the characters perfectly fine. It seems to be an issue reading the output of the script into Java.

Comment: @Cristian: What *exactly* do you mean by "perfectly fine" though? I dare say the output is correct *in some encoding* but unless you know what the encoding is, it's useless.

Comment: @JonSkeet If I echo the title name and pass it to Java as shown in my OP then it works fine, displaying the ASCII characters, leading me to think the problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: @Cristian the default Java encoding is UTF-16 afaik, but that isn't relevant, as the program being called is not Java.

Comment: @JonSkeet I'm talking about system encoding (meaning the os, not the java system). I should probably clarify that.

Comment: @iwein: The default Java encoding (default for String.getBytes etc) depends on the platform. It's *not* the same thing as the internal representation of `char`.

Answer (score -4):

**Update :**

Even the program print the output with `UTF-8`, I am not sure, you will be see your expected output or may be not. Because of, when I test with `Eclipse IDE` other encoding format, I cannot see my output(Japanese Character). But when I change to `UTF-8` encoding in IDE. I see Japanese Character. That why, it is also depend on your environment encoding system.

```
String output = null;
while ((output = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
    String utf8OutPut = output.getBytes("UTF-8");
    System.out.println(utf8OutPut);
}
```

Comment: It's not the command itself that needs encoding. It's the *output of the process* which is the problem. Additionally, your text before the code is *extremely* unclear.

Comment: @Jon Skeet, I thought, it is a example command to show in the post. What will happen there is a special character in actual command?

Comment: @JonSkeet Sorry, I did careless the question. Now I get main point which is output. I will update the answer.